# error al compilar un procedimiento de almacenado en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estimados buenas noches.

solicito su ayuda con el siguiente script

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_ingresar_cliente AS
    CURSOR cur_id_cli IS
            SELECT id_cliente FROM registro_cliente ORDER BY id_cliente DESC;
    PROCEDURE prc_ingreso_clientes (
    rut_cliente             IN registro_cliente.rut_cliente%TYPE,
    nombre_cliente          IN registro_cliente.nombre_cliente%TYPE,
    telefono_cliente        IN registro_cliente.telefono_cliente%TYPE,
    correo_cliente          IN registro_cliente.correo_cliente%TYPE,
    direccion_cliente       IN registro_cliente.direccion_cliente%TYPE,
    ifEmpresa               IN registro_cliente.ifEmpresa%TYPE,
    sexo_cliente            IN registro_cliente.sexo_cliente%TYPE,
    perfil_id_perfil        IN registro_cliente.perfil_id_perfil%TYPE,
    tarjeta_id_tarjeta      IN registro_cliente.tarjeta_id_tarjeta%TYPE,
    sucursal_id_sucursal    IN registro_cliente.sucursal_id_sucursal%TYPE);
    END pkg_ingresar_cliente;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_ingresar_cliente AS
    PROCEDURE prc_ingreso_clientes (
    rut_cliente             IN registro_cliente.rut_cliente%TYPE,
    nombre_cliente          IN registro_cliente.nombre_cliente%TYPE,
    telefono_cliente        IN registro_cliente.telefono_cliente%TYPE,
    correo_cliente          IN registro_cliente.correo_cliente%TYPE,
    direccion_cliente       IN registro_cliente.direccion_cliente%TYPE,
    ifEmpresa               IN registro_cliente.ifEmpresa%TYPE,
    sexo_cliente            IN registro_cliente.sexo_cliente%TYPE,
    perfil_id_perfil        IN registro_cliente.perfil_id_perfil%TYPE,
    tarjeta_id_tarjeta      IN registro_cliente.tarjeta_id_tarjeta%TYPE,
    sucursal_id_sucursal    IN registro_cliente.sucursal_id_sucursal%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
    FOR i IN cur_id_cli
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO registro_cliente VALUES (id_cliente_seq.NEXTVAL,rut_cliente,nombre_cliente,telefono_cliente,
correo_cliente,direccion_cliente,ifEmpresa,
        sexo_cliente,perfil_id_perfil,tarjeta_id_tarjeta,sucursal_id_sucursal);
    END LOOP;
    END prc_ingreso_clientes;
    END pkg_ingresar_cliente;
```

al compilar me arroga este error

> Error(12,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

aun no le encuentro solución y quería pedir si alguno pudiese ayudarme para darle una respuesta a esta solicitud.

desde ya, les agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En principio debería compilar bien, no veo ningún error. Prueba a poner un slash (/) después de las dos instrucciones

```
END pkg_ingresar_cliente;
/
```